# Java/Scala - Convert xml to json

Tags: java, json, xml, scala

I want to convert XML to JSON using either Java or Scala. Below is the working code, but here I am not able to see any identifier for XML attributes in Json to differentiate it with elements.
I need help to get XML attributes with identifier(@) in Json output.

Input XML :

```
      <Test>
        <AttrTest Code="199" Pro="Intel"  Version="9.106">
            <Info>FD2F</Info>
        </AttrTest>
      </Test>
```

Code :

```
    import org.json.XML
            def xmlToJson(xml: String) = {
              var PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4
              try {
                val xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml)
                val jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR)
                jsonPrettyPrintString
              } catch {
                case ex: Exception =>
                  println(ex.toString)
              }
            }

           val xmlStr = "<Test>\n\t\t<AttrTest Code=\"199\" Pro=\"Intel\"  Version=\"9.106\">\n\t\t<Info>FD2F</Info>\n</AttrTest>\n</Test>\n\t"
            println(xmlToJson(xmlStr))
```

Output :

```
        {"Test": {"AttrTest": {
            "Version": 9.106,
            "Pro": "Intel",
            "Info": "FD2F",
            "Code": 199
        }}}
```

Expected Output :

```
        {"Test": {"AttrTest": {
            "@Version": 9.106,
            "@Pro": "Intel",
            "Info": "FD2F",
            "@Code": 199
        }}}
```

Please help.

Comment: Underscore-java library can convert xml to json. U.xmlToJson(xml) method will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible with the library you are using. Here's from their docs:

> Some information may be lost in this transformation because JSON is a data format and XML is a document format. XML uses elements, attributes, and content text, while JSON uses unordered collections of name/value pairs and arrays of values. **JSON does not does not like to distinguish between elements and attributes.**

You may try looking into other XML->JSON libraries or implement a pre-conversion step that would, say, append a "@" prefix to each node's attribute.